# How to delete Firebase snapshot from array?

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function that listens for new objects added to the Firebase database, appends those new objects to an array, and then populates a tableView using that array. I can't figure out how to then remove an object from the array once it has been deleted. I think I'm on the right track but I don't know how to "undo" an append.

Here's what I have so far:

```
func configureDatabase() {

    // Listen for new messages in the Firebase database
    let ref = self.rootRef.child("invites").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

    self.invites.append(snapshot)
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: self.invites.count-1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    })

    //listen for deleted messages in Firebase database
    let ref2 = self.rootRef.child("invites").observeEventType(.ChildRemoved, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

     //remove from invites array and refresh table??
    })
}
```

Do I have to pass the value from the actual cell in the table?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AlertCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AlertCell

        //get user, set cell text
        let inviteDict = invites[indexPath.row].value as! [String : AnyObject]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in sample code on the Firebase website:

```
// Listen for deleted comments in the Firebase database
    commentsRef.observeEventType(.ChildRemoved, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
      let index = self.indexOfMessage(snapshot)
      self.comments.removeAtIndex(index)
      self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 1)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    })

func indexOfMessage(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) -> Int {
    var index = 0
    for  comment in self.comments {
      if (snapshot.key == comment.key) {
        return index
      }
      index += 1
    }
    return -1
  }
```